# What 120VAC devices can take 150VDC?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power

I am looking at a portable inverter that claims to be able to output two modes through its Type B socket: 120V AC or 150V "HVDC". The documentation says the 150VDC mode can be used for resistive loads or for switched mode power supplies, avoiding conversion loss from the inverter. How can I tell what black box device normally rated for 120VAC can take 150VDC? Some SMPS have filters before rectification and I'm concerned the filter will short / not work on DC.

Comment: To be safe: those that say so on their case/documentation.

Comment: I'd expect SMPS units that are specced for "dual voltage" (100-240VAC) to work.

Comment: @pjc50 Some SMPS units with PFC front ends will have trouble with a DC input.

Comment: @pjc50 Some true dual where really dual 100-120 or 220-240 with auto voltage doubler. What you are looking for is a _wide range_ power supply. Most will cope with DC but the fuse will not when there is an error.

Comment: Few things to consider when running something on DC intended for AC: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Sz0ksWWfJyM and https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY

Answer (score 1):

If its internal bus rail (prior to the final switching stage) is 150 volts DC then, when feeding its bridge output it would be able to generate possibly up to 300 Vp-p or a sinewave of only 106 V RMS. This tells me that it's not a high quality device because, to achieve an RMS of 120 V, would need an internal bus rail that is a about 50% of the peak-to-peak of 120 V = 339/2 = 170 volts DC.

Basically what I'm saying is read the small print because it may just be a square wave converter and possibly incapable of delivering enough voltage to some 120 V AC appliances. It may even cause problems with other appliances due to the harmonics.

> How can I tell what black box device normally rated for 120VAC can
>   take 150VDC?

That is difficult because it's not normally stated. Given what I said above I would look at a few other inverters and read the details in the spec sheets. If details are not available then I would be suspicious of its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell what black box device normally rated for 120VAC can take 150VDC?

By looking at the nameplate.  Just about everything you plug into the wall has a little plaque or writing near where the line power connection is.  That tells you the voltage range and frequency the device requires, and the maximum power it will draw.

Many modern electronic devices can take "universal" line power.  That's usually 100-240 V, 50-60 Hz.  If you have such a device, then you can use your inverter on the 150 V setting to get a little more efficiency from the inverter.

**However**, this is also dangerous.  It will be easy to forget that what looks like a standard outlet doesn't have standard voltage.  The universal power device you plug in will be fine, but months later when you or someone else plugs in a regular "115 V" device - poof!